# Version solving failed - flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using Google map in my flutter application and added below line in pubspec.yaml file :

```
custom_marker: ^1.0.0
```

performed pub get, but it gives me below error :

> Because flutter_html >=2.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.0-alpha.1 depends on flutter_svg >=0.22.0 <1.0.0 and every version of custom_marker depends on flutter_svg ^1.0.1, flutter_html >=2.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.0-alpha.1 is incompatible with custom_marker.
> So, because mahotsav depends on both custom_marker ^1.0.0 and flutter_html ^2.2.0, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because mahotsav depends on both custom_marker ^1.0.0 and flutter_html ^2.2.0, version solving failed.)

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the prerelease version of the package it will remove the error.

```
dependencies:
    flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try updating to prerelease version of `flutter_html`.

In your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
```

And then run: `flutter pub get`